# Table hangs on Update query Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-update

I am updating one Oracle table field in reference to another table having similar Key fields but on this Particular table the Update hangs for upto ten Minutes. This Update on another table having the same Number Of records executes in a few swconds. Is there a faster way to Update the Table or what is the Problem with My query?

```
update MAINRETAIL_MIG s set s. accountid = (
select e. accountid from accounts e where s.ORGKEY = e.ORGKEY);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created index on orgkey field and the Update goes first.